# What should I do when Xcode says a previously commited file is unversioned?

Tags: xcode, git

Occasionally, Xcode shows "File is Unversioned" in the Version Editor (and shows a question mark by its name) for a file that has already been updated and committed several times in the past.  If I go ahead and commit the file again, Xcode then shows the complete history in the Version Editor.  I did not rename or move the file when this happens.

Is there a way I can force Xcode/git to recognize the file without re-committing it?

I'm currently using Xcode 10.2.1.

Comment: Basically, Xcode's version control support is buggy. Laugh uproariously and ignore the problem. Even better, ignore Xcode's version control support: I use the command line, or else a good GUI git interface like Sourcetree.

Comment: So, if I issue a command like "git log -p filename", you expect it to work?

Comment: Next time this comes up, try it and see.

Answer (score 0):

I used the command line once

`git add .`

`git commit -m "your commit message"`

`git push origin main`

After that, everything on XCode Source Control worked as per usual.